# WordPress frontend AJAX call to trash post failing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

My users have the ability to create an instance of a custom post from their accounts, and then I would like for them also to be able to delete them.  Within a section of their account all the posts they have made are listed, and each has a "delete" button like so:

`<a href="#" class="deleteMR" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>">delete</a>`

Then in an external JS file I have:

```
jQuery(".deleteMR").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   rid = $(this).attr("data-id");
   var data =  {
      action: 'delete_request',            
      requestid: rid,        
   }
   jQuery.post(my_ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
      if(response.success) {
         alert('It worked');
      } else {
         alert('It failed');
      }
    });
});
```

And then in my functions.php I have:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_request', 'delete_request');
function delete_request() {

   $requestid = $_REQUEST['requestid'];
   wp_trash_post(requestid);

   wp_send_json_success(true);

   wp_send_json_error(console.log(response));
}
```

When the button is clicked, the JavaScript correctly triggers (and I have checked its picking up the correct post ID with console.log's), the function in functions.php is at least acknowledged but the return is always "failed" and the post is not trashed.  If I output `$response` instead I just seem to get the first 10% of the code of the page that this whole thing is triggered from.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW the issue was resolved by me moving the ajax specific JS to it's own file and then enqueuing it in it's own function separate from the one that enqueues all my other JS files.  Couldn't tell you how it fixed it, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

There's couple of things wrong with your code. Please see the comments I added in the code below.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_request', 'delete_request');
function delete_request() {

   $requestid = $_REQUEST['requestid'];
   // missing $ from variable name
   wp_trash_post(requestid);
   // always returns a success response
   wp_send_json_success(true); 
   // error response never gets returned as success response is sent first.
   // also console.log is javascript, use var_dump or print_r instead
   wp_send_json_error(console.log(response)); 
}
```

If you write you're code like this, I think the post trashing should work.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_request', 'delete_request');
function delete_request() {

  // check nonce wp_verify_nonce()
  // send nonce with your ajax request
  // get nonce from wp_create_nonce() added to your site with wp_localize_script()

  // check capabilities with current_user_can();

  if ( ! empty( $_POST['requestid'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['requestid'] ) ) {

    $trashed = wp_trash_post( intval( $_POST['requestid'] ) );

    if ( $trashed ) {    
      wp_send_json_success('Trashing post succeeded');          
    } else {    
      wp_send_json_error('Trashing post failed');          
    }

  } else {

    wp_send_json_error('Post id missing');

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see some noob mistakes there so thanks for pointing  them out, all the rest of your suggestions make sense - however I tried them out and it doesn't appear to be working.  In my JavaScript I am now just outputting `alert(response);` and the contents of the alert is still the top of the page i'm calling all this from (doctype declaration down to the title tag).

Comment: @Zeb That's strange, I tested the code (your link, jquery, and my ajax function)  in my local sandbox WP install and it worked as expected. Do you have `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` set to true in your `config.php`? Are there any errors in the `error_log`? And what does your browser's network tab show as response you when the ajax post request is fired? Are there any errors in the console after the request?

Comment: I just enabled debug and logs and ran the function a couple more times, but not generating the file.  As for the network tab, when I click the button it creates a new entry for 'my-media-requests/' (the url am calling from) but no errors.  Really stumped :/

Comment: @Zeb So the ajax request is sent to 'my-media-requests/' and not admin-ajax.php? How are you setting `my_ajax_object.ajaxurl`?

Comment: It would appear so yes.  I when I enqueue my files I am setting the `my_ajax_object` there.  Like so:

`function styles_and_scripts() {` ... `wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sitewide.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true ); wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );` ... `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'styles_and_scripts' );`